# Fiber product of separated schemes is again separated.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fibre-product

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two separated schemes. I want to prove that their fiber product $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}Y$ is also a separated scheme.

Note that we have the maps 
$$f:X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$$ 
$$g:Y\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$$ 
and the projection maps $p_{1}:X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}Y\rightarrow X$ and $p_{2}:X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}Y\rightarrow Y$such that $f\circ p_{1} = g\circ p_{2}$. I want to show that the induced morphism $\varphi:=f\circ p_{1}=g\circ p_{2}: X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}Y\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is separated. This comes down to showing that the image of the diagonal morphism 
$$\Delta_{X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Y/\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}:X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Y\rightarrow (X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}\times Y)\times_{\mathbb{Z}}(X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}\times Y)$$ 
is closed.

By assumption we have that the $\Delta_{X/\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}(X)$ and $\Delta_{Y/\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}(Y)$ are closed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: remark -- If you've proven the valuative criterion already, it will make this a little easier!

Comment: @hunter Haven't heard of this statement before. I think that I found another approach. Namely by using the fact that the composition of two separated morphisms is again separated, and the base change of a separated morphism is separated. Meaning that $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are separated, since they are the base change of $f$ and $g$ respectively. And therefore $\varphi = f\circ p_{1}$ is separated.

Comment: @George this is a correct solution to your problem, see [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KU) for confirmation. You should post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the confirmation. As suggested, I posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the base change of a separated morphism is again separated.

Since the maps $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are base changes of the given separated morphisms $f$ and $g$ respectively, we find that $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are also separated morphisms.

Since the composition of two separated morphisms is again separated we find that the map $\varphi:=f\circ p_{1}=g\circ p_{2}$ is also separated.

This proves that the fiber product of two separated schemes is indeed also a separated scheme.